# selenium execute_script with newlines

Tags: javascript, python, string, selenium

I'm using selenium and Python and I am trying to execute a JS function that takes in a string like so:

```
browser.execute_script("foo('someString')")
```

This works when someString does not have any newlines. 
When there is a newline character the following happens:

```
\n     => Parse Error
\\n    => Newline is converted to a space
\r\n   => Parse Error
\\r\\n => Both characters are converted to a space
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass arguments to the javascript; those additional arguments are accessible using `arguments`:

```
browser.execute_script("foo(arguments[0])", 'someString')
browser.execute_script("foo(arguments[0])", 'string with \n is also ok!\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I don't get a parse error anymore but the newlines are being removed alltogether. So the string "hello\nworld" becomes "helloworld".

Comment: @MinaHany, How do you confirm that newlines are gone? Could you try this: `browser.execute_script("console.log(arguments[0])", 'hello\n newline')`

Comment: @MinaHany, If the `foo` write the string to html, you may need to convert newlines something like `<br>`: `browser.execute_script("foo(arguments[0])", 'hello\n newline\n'.replace('<br>'))`

Comment: You were right, the problem was not selenium. There was a function 3 levels down from foo() that removes the newline. Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction! However to solve my problem I need to somehow override the function that removes the newline (I know its name). Is it possible to do that in selenium before executing the foo function?

Comment: @MinaHany, Could you post a separate question with the content of the functions? Without seeing it I can't answer.

Comment: It is done, I just redefined the function to return the string as is. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is to convert `\n` to unicode `\u000a`.

**similar example**:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('website_name').value='hello1\u000ahello2'")
```